# How to get the bounding box of text on the screen in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a WinForms TextBox control, how can I obtain, in screen coordinates the bounding box of the text as a specified character position?  I know the start index and end index of the text in question, but given those two values, how can I find the bounding box of that text?

To be clear... I know how to get the bounding box of the control itself.  I need the bounding box of a substring of the TextBox.Text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with `Graphics.MeasureString` but couldn't get accurate results. The following code gives me fairly consistent results at different font sizes with `Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges`.

```
private Rectangle GetTextBounds(TextBox textBox, int startPosition, int length)
{
  using (Graphics g = textBox.CreateGraphics())
  {
    g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

    CharacterRange[] characterRanges = { new CharacterRange(startPosition, length) };
    StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    stringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(characterRanges);

    Region region = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(textBox.Text, textBox.Font,
                                             textBox.Bounds, stringFormat)[0];
    Rectangle bounds = Rectangle.Round(region.GetBounds(g));

    Point textOffset = textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(0);

    return new Rectangle(textBox.Margin.Left + bounds.Left + textOffset.X,
                         textBox.Margin.Top + textBox.Location.Y + textOffset.Y,
                         bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
  }
}
```

This snippet just places a panel on top of my TextBox to illustrate the computed rectangle.

```
...
Rectangle r = GetTextBounds(textBox1, 2, 10);
Panel panel = new Panel
{
  Bounds = r,
  BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
};

this.Controls.Add(panel);
panel.Show();
panel.BringToFront();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can use [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx). You can get graphics object for form using CreateGraphics method. Let's say, you have to find bounding box for "World" in "Hello World". So first measure "Hello " string - that would give you width of "Hello " that in turn will tell you left position. Then measure actual word to get right position.